# Is there a `flip` function in the OCaml standard library?

Tags: ocaml

In Haskell, we have a `flip` function: `flip f x y = f y x`, which essentially takes a function and returns the same function except that the two arguments are swapped. I wonder if there is a counterpart in OCaml, since I could not find one and don't want to rewrite it every time.

Cheers,

Comment: [The OCaml equivalent of Hoogle doesn't seem to find anything](http://search.ocaml.jp/?q=%28%27a+-%3E+%27b+-%3E+%27c%29+-%3E+%27b+-%3E+%27a+-%3E+%27c), at least.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Many functions like this for generalized FP plumbing aren't defined in the standard OCaml library. I have always missed them.

However, nowadays there are good OCaml libraries that supply most or all of these missing functions. The [OCaml Batteries Included](http://batteries.forge.ocamlcore.org) project defines [`flip`](https://ocaml-batteries-team.github.io/batteries-included/hdoc2/BatPervasives.html#VALflip) in the `BatPervasives` module. The Jane Street [Core](https://janestreet.github.io/) project defines [`flip`](https://ocaml.janestreet.com/ocaml-core/latest/doc/core_kernel/Core_kernel/Fn/index.html#val-flip) in the `Fn` module.

Comment: In core the function is `Fn.flip`

Comment: Thanks a lot. Lucky that it's been defined in Core.

Answer (score 7):

Now `Fun.flip` in [included](https://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Fun.html#VALflip) in the standard library as of OCaml 4.08.

Answer (score 5):

The pain is somewhat mitigated by labeled arguments:

```
# let f ~x ~y = x - y;; 
val f : x:int -> y:int -> int = <fun>
# f ~y:5;;
- : x:int -> int = <fun>
# f ~x:6;;
- : y:int -> int = <fun>
```

Thus if you're willing to write down the labels (which some argue makes code more readable) then you may be able to get the behavior you want.  It depends on the situation of course.

Comment: `flip` is actually more useful in contexts of partial application. A simple example would be a function to subtract a number by 2: `flip (-) 2`